# How to set up sqlite database in flutter with null safety?

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, sqflite, dart-null-safety

I've been struggling for a while to set up a sqlite database with sqflite in flutter. Code is producing a new instance of the database every time I call the getter method for a database. Here is the code:

```
class DatabaseProvider {
  DatabaseProvider._();
  static final DatabaseProvider dbProvider = DatabaseProvider._();

  static Database? _database;

  Future<Database> get database async => _database ??= await _createDatabase();
}
...
```

Comment: what `_createDatabase()` do in your code? Does it initialize the `_database` ?

Comment: Yes, it's opening database with `await openDatabase()` and returning `Future<Database>`

Comment: then, did you set the returned object to `_database`?, something like: `_database = await openDatabase()`?

Comment: I didn't set returned object to `_database` because `_database` is assigned to `_createDatabase()` and that function is returning `Database` object. I tried to change getter method to `if (_database != null) return _database!` and `_database = await _createDatabase()`. But still same. Every time I try to insert to database I get new database instance with only one entry.

Comment: How about: `Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database == null) {
      _database = await _createDatabase();
    }
    return _database;
  }` ?

Comment: I am getting and error: `A value of type 'Database?' can't be returned from the function 'database' because it has a return type of 'Future<Database>'` and a warning: `Prefer using ??= over testing for null.`. And if I change return type to `<Database?>` I get an error in my provider as well: `The method 'insert' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the `_database` in your getter. So, change it to this:

```
Future<Database> get database async {
  if (_database == null) {
     // initialize database from _createDatabase result.
    _database = await _createDatabase();
  }
  // because _database have beeen initialized above, 
  // then we can use ! to tell that the _database can't be null.
  return _database!;
}
```

Comment: Can `late` be used in some way?